# SvelteKit protected routes: localStorage is not defined

Tags: typescript, svelte, sveltekit

I'm trying to protect routes, or redirect to the login when `auth_token` isn't in local storage.

In my `src/routes/+layout.server.ts` I have:

```
import { redirect } from "@sveltejs/kit"
import type { LayoutServerLoad } from "./$types"

export const load: LayoutServerLoad = async ({ locals }) => {
    if (localStorage.getItem('auth_token') === null) {
        throw redirect(303, '/')
    }
}
```

Although I'm getting:

> ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined?

Comment: Well, `localStorage` is a browser API and your code is covered in the word **server** so ‍♂️

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)